# Windows 8 store freezes when searching for updates

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I'm running Windows 8 Pro (x64) on my home desktop.   Everything is working well (very very differently, but well) except for the Store application.   Several days ago, I got an update notification that listed 8 application updates.   I hit the link to install the updates, but only six of them installed.

Now I have *Updates(2)* showing in the store's notification area, and whenever I try to look for the updates the Store goes into "searching" mode (the circles/dots animation) and never finishes the search.  Is there any way that I can reset the Store app?   I have tried re-downloading it with no success.

Comment: Maybe the servers are under heavy load? Try over the next few days and see if it sorts itself out.

Comment: Does the Event Log report anything? What's using a lot of CPU in the task manager?

Comment: It's been happening for several days now, so I don't think it's load related.

Comment: Nothing odd in the event log, and CPU usage is under 5% (on an 8 core machine).   Rebooting does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually did a System Restore and the problem is gone.  I'm not sure what caused it - I assume that I installed some other software that interfered with the Store's ability to communicate.  The only thing that comes to mind is a Diablo III update, but I'm not sure whether that could have caused the problem.  At any rate it's working now.